# Ext.Window show method open window behind current opened window in extjs 3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I am not getting new window on current window after performing **window.show()** method.

This JS code for **current window** :

```
stPopupWindow = new top.Ext.Window({
            title : title,
            id : 'stPopupWindowId', 
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: screenWidth,
            height: screenHeight,
            draggable: false,modal:true,closeAction:'close',plain: true,
            layout:'fit',
            autoScroll:true,
            maximizable : true,
            minimizable : true,
            items:[...]});
```

This JS code for **I am trying to open another window from current window**. But It would open behind the current window. :

```
popupWindowFileUpload = new Ext.Window({ 
    title : "Upload Files", 
    id : 'popupWindowFileUploadId', 
    layout:'fit', 
    width:470,
    height:250,
    draggable: false,
    modal:true,
    closeAction: 'close',
    plain: true,
    maximizable : true,
    minimizable : true,
    items:[pnlFileUpload]
});
popupWindowFileUpload.show();
```

**Note :** I can see that window after closing current window. 
If you know something related to this problem than please tell me, Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should call the toFront() window method

```
popupWindowFileUpload.show();
popupWindowFileUpload.toFront();
```

Comment: I just ran into this same problem after upgrading to ExtJs 6.2 (worked fine in 6.0).  While your answer is correct the docs specifically say "After being shown, a floating Component (such as a Ext.window.Window), is activated it and brought to the front of its z-index stack."  This behavior has apparently been broken.